# How to highlight Nav Menu on scroll the component with react?

Tags: reactjs, react-navigation, react-scroll

I want to highlight the nav menu when scrolling this component in react.

If the Navbar is "Home About Products"

When I will scroll in the about section, About nav menu will be active or highlight.

How can I do this in react and is there any npm package for this?

Comment: I solve this problem using react-scroll npm package. Thank you everyone

Answer (score 0):

You can use intersection observer.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API

or

You can also use waypoint Library
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-waypoint